# How to query external database for Count

Tags: 8, database

How do I query the below SQL query to an external database table from Drupal 8 custom module,

```
Select Count(requestID) FROM requestDB.request where request.dateCreated >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY) and ek_borrowerID = 111;
```

I have configured the settings.php already. Below is the query I tried to build, but it does not work

```
Database::setActiveConnection('requestDB');
$db = Database::getConnection();
$db->select('request')
    ->fields('request', array('Count(requestID)'))
    ->condition('dateCreated','DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY)', '>=')
    ->condition('ek_borrowerID','111')
    ->execute();
Database::setActiveConnection();
```

Comment: Did you already check the [documentation on count queries](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/count-queries)? I am pretty sure the fields-section should match with actual database fields and you cannot use expressions in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not selecting the default database for the new connection.

Try:

```
$select = Database::getConnection('default', 'requestDB')->select('request');
$select->addExpression('Count(requestID)', 'rec_count');
$select->condition('dateCreated','DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY)', '>=');
$select->condition('ek_borrowerID','111');
$select->execute();
```

With this method you dont need to switch back to your original database as this just creates a temporary connection.

Also you need to use addExpression for your count as mentioned by Charles Bamford below

Comment: I am able to get the count using the addExpression but the dateCreated condition does not return any records. Do you know how I can fetch the last 30 days records?

Comment: i had to use '<=' and it worked! cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [->addExpression()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Select.php/function/Select%3A%3AaddExpression/8.2.x) instead of ->fields()